# properties of canonical algebra homomorphism $\varphi:U(L(A))→A$ for $A$ commutative, associative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

I am working on the following task: 
Let $A$ be an associative algebra and $B$ a basis of $A$. Let $L(B)$ be the free Lie algebra over $A$. Show: There exists a canonical algebra homomorphism $\varphi:U(L(B))→A$. What can we say about the homomorphism when $A$ is commutative?

Initially, we have the inclusion mapping $\phi:B\to A$.
In accordance with the definition, a homomorphism $\psi:L(B)\to A$ with $\psi(b)=b$ for every $b\in B$ exists. It follows, that a algebra homomorphism $\varphi:U(L(B))\to A$ exists.

I understand the existence of the homomorphism; however, I am not aware of the additional statement that can be made when $A$ is abelian. Can we make a statement about $[U(L(B)),U(L(B))]?$
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you mean $L(B)$ instead of $L(A)$? otherwise there is no need to actually use the basis as all the structure you need is actually there!

Comment: @Felix Oh, of course! Thank you, I just edited it.

Comment: actually with all of $A$ it would have been easier, however, short hint, what happens with $[b,b']$. then you should be done to completely characterize the map!

Comment: @Felix if $A$ is commutative, $[b,b^{\prime}]=0$. Is $L(B)$ then just the trivial Lie algebra?

Comment: no, $L(B)$ cannot be a trivial lie algebra, it is a free algebra on more than one generator. However, you nailed down the map! For both, $L(B)$ and $U(L(B))$ you know precisely how the elements look like, so you can literally write everything down. the map will be quite boring though!

Comment: @Felix I'm somehow drawing a blank at the moment. $\varphi$ cannot be the identity on $B$, right?

Comment: of course it can, that is literally all the job it has! (that is literally the universal property of a free object)

Comment: @Felix Thank you! That was somehow too obvious :)

Comment: "I like being lost in the woods, it is the only way I can see a clear path" Mal Reynolds, Firefly